# How to load an image with image-webpack-loader 2019?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to load a jpg file to my project using `image-webpack-loader` but I am getting an error. I can't figure out what's wrong.

This is my Webpack config

```
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
var path = require('path');

const htmlPlugin = new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
  template: "./src/index.html",
  filename: "./index.html"
});

module.exports = {
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader"
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'style-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
              importLoaders: 1,
              localIdentName: "[name]_[local]_[hash:base64]",
              sourceMap: true,
              minimize: true
            }
          }

        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              mozjpeg: {
                progressive: true,
                quality: 65
              },
              // optipng.enabled: false will disable optipng
              optipng: {
                enabled: false,
              },
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4
              },
              gifsicle: {
                interlaced: false,
              },
              // the webp option will enable WEBP
              webp: {
                quality: 75
              }
            }
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [htmlPlugin]
};
```

I have an image file `trial.jpg` that I am trying to import to `data.js`

```
import test from "./trial.jpg"
```

both of these files are in the same folder for now

this is the error I get

```
> webpack-dev-server --mode development --open

i ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:8080/
i ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /
i ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from c:\workplace\newtrial
i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
× ｢wdm｣: Hash: 615e07cebfea73d02177
Version: webpack 4.41.2
Time: 3117ms
Built at: 12/24/2019 4:15:57 AM
          Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
   ./index.html  793 bytes          [emitted]
index_bundle.js   1.43 MiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = index_bundle.js
[0] multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./src 40 bytes {main} [built]
[./data.js] 1.72 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/ansi-html/index.js] 4.16 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react-dom/index.js] 1.33 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/react/index.js] 190 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://localhost:8080] (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 4.29 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/overlay.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/overlay.js 3.51 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/socket.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/socket.js 1.53 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/createSocketUrl.js 2.89 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/log.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/log.js 964 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/reloadApp.js 1.59 KiB {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js] (webpack)-dev-server/client/utils/sendMessage.js 402 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js] (webpack)-dev-server/node_modules/strip-ansi/index.js 161 bytes {main} [built]
[./node_modules/webpack/hot sync ^\.\/log$] (webpack)/hot sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes {main} [built]
[./src/index.js] 2.3 KiB {main} [built]
    + 31 hidden modules

ERROR in ./trial.jpg
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/image-webpack-loader/index.js):
c:\workplace\newtrial\node_modules\imagemin\index.js:42
module.exports = async (input, {glob = true, ...options} = {}) => {
                                             ^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:53:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:95:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:543:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\workplace\newtrial\node_modules\image-webpack-loader\index.js:1:78)
 @ ./data.js 1:0-31
 @ ./src/index.js
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
    Entrypoint undefined = ./index.html
    [./node_modules/html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js!./src/index.html] 965 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/lodash/lodash.js] 528 KiB {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/global.js] (webpack)/buildin/global.js 472 bytes {0} [built]
    [./node_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 497 bytes {0} [built]
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

I am new to React. I don't understand what I am doing wrong.